# Prove $f$ is constant if a condition on a differentiable curve is satisfied

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain, $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ a differentiable mapping. I need to show that $f$ is constant iff for every differentiable curve $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow G, \,\,\gamma' (t)\in \text{ker} Df(\gamma(t)) \,\,\forall t \in ]0,1[.$ We set $\gamma'(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Given that $G$ is a domain, for $x,y \in G$ there exists a path connecting $x$ and $y$ which is (given our assumptions) differentiable, $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow G, \,\,\gamma (0) = x, \,\,\gamma (1) = y.$

Can somebody provide more insight or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: One direction is easy. For the other, pick such a $\gamma$ and calculate $(f \circ \gamma)'$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is constant, then the "kernel-condition" is trivially satisfied because $Df(\xi) = 0$ everywhere.

Now assume that $f$ is not constant. Let $x,y \in D$ such that $f(x) \ne f(y)$. Let $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow G$ be differentiable with $\gamma (0) = x, \,\,\gamma (1) = y$. If $f_i$ are the coordinate functions of $f$, then for some $i$ we must have $f_i\gamma(0) \ne f_i\gamma(1)$. This shows $(f_i\gamma)'$ cannot be $0$ in all $t \in (0,1)$. Pick $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $(f_i\gamma)'(t_0) \ne 0$. The chain rule says that $(f_i\gamma)'(t_0) = Df_i(\gamma(t_0)) (\gamma'(t_0))$. But $Df_i(\xi)$ is the $i$-th row of $Df(\xi)$, hence
$$Df(\gamma(t_0))(\gamma'(t_0) \ne 0 .$$
Hence the kernel-condition is violated.